# What is another word for "character-building"?

Tags: character-development, terminology

I want to say that the author uses Character A's "character development" to explore Character B.

In other words, the author builds on the personality of A to exemplify the nature of B.

What is another word that replaces "character development" in the context above?

Comment: I'm voting to close as it's entirely opinion based what a suitable replacement word would be

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there are a lot of words that might work, but I'm not sure if they are exactly what you are looking for:

Complimentary, contrast, juxtapose: All mean to compare, possibly opposing, elements.

Take a look at some of the language in this blog post referencing [Robert McKee](https://noveldog.com/2009/08/30/how-many-characters-do-you-need/).

Answer (score 1):

Hm, good question. Since you stated that one character’s development can explore another, then there is a synthesis, some symbiosis. I am not in reach of a dictionary, but if I could give an opinion instead of a real word in this case, I would say “commetamorphous” or “commetamorphicity”

The Latin prefix *cum* + Greek *meta* + Greek *morphē*

*cum* = with (this prefix implies more than one)
*meta* = after (this prefix implies a timescale)
*morphē* = shape, form, appearance

An obvious example is metamorphosis, which implies a change of form.

The only addition is *cum* which, by some laws of language I forget, changes to com- in the prefix. We now have a word to denote a change together (character α & β), thus they develop together.

In this case I would define as such:

Commetamorphicity: a character development method which uses one character to develop another.

I hope this helps (: